# Excel VBA Debug.Print trick

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

This might be get marked as a bad question, but I vaguely remember in the past doing something like this in the immediate window of the Excel VBA editor:

```
Debug.Print someRange ,,0,
```

I honestly don't remember how the `,,0,` changed the output (I think it showed the range address or something), and I'm also pretty sure that it's NOT the correct mix of commas and zeros.  But I do remember that it was helpful and I hope someone recognizes it and can explain it, so that I can add this to my debugging repertoire.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example doesn't look like anything I have seen, but possibly you meant something like mentioned in this article: http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson18/p17.html

Comment: The comma operator seems to align output values as a table, e.g. `Debug.Print Range("A1"),Range("A2"),1,2` will print `a             c              1             2 ` if `A1 = a` and `A2 = c`.

Comment: Maybe       Debug.Print Range(someRange).Address

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, nope, it was definitely ,,0, or ,0,,, or something like that.  I'll dig around more and see what I can find out... Thought for sure I'd have emailed it to myself.

Comment: Actually I see "Debug.Print myRange.Address(0,0,,True)" which looks vaguely familiar...but what is it doing?  (http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/385012-debug-print-range-full-address.html)

Comment: In the context you just posted, if you look at the VBA Object Browser for 'Address', you get the following options: Property Address([RowAbsolute], [ColumnAbsolute], [ReferenceStyle As XlReferenceStyle = xlA1], [External], [RelativeTo]) As String